# How can I move a variable and echo above the table without messing up the table structure in php?

Tags: php

What I want is the    `echo "<p>Average Mark: $average</p>";` to appear above the table rather than below the table. If I do this though the problem is that it won't calculate the average as the echo is above the variable. But if I move the variable and with it the while loop above the whole table as I also need the while loop to select the `$row[Mark]'` field from a query as that is the field that is going to be averaged, it messes up the structure of the table. How can I display the `$average, $total, $count` etc variables and  `echo "<p>Average Mark: $average</p>";` above the table without messing up the table structure?

Below is current code and you can see the `$count++; , $total += $row['Mark'];` in the while loop and the $average variable and echo at the bottom.

```
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close();



 ?>
<table border='1'>
      <tr>
      <th>Session ID</th>
      <th>TeacherUsername</th>
      <th>Teacher Name</th>
      <th>Module Number</th>
      <th>Module Name</th>
      <th>Course ID</th>
      <th>Course Name</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Student Username</th>
      <th>Student Name</th>
      <th>Mark</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      </tr>
      <?php
       $total = 0;
        $count = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $count++;
          $total += $row['Mark'];
          echo "
      <tr>
      <td>{$row['SessionId']}</td>
      <td>{$row['TeacherUsername']}</td>
      <td>{$row['TeacherForename']} {$row['TeacherSurname']}</td>
      <td>{$row['ModuleId']}</td>
      <td>{$row['ModuleName']}</td>
      <td>{$row['CourseId']}</td>
      <td>{$row['CourseName']}</td>
      <td>{$row['Year']}</td>
      <td>{$row['StudentUsername']}</td>
      <td>{$row['StudentForename']} {$row['StudentSurname']}</td>
      <td>{$row['Mark']}</td>
      <td>{$row['Grade']}</td>
      </tr>";
        }
        ?>

        </table>

    <?php
    $average = (int)($total/$count);
    echo "<p>Average Mark: $average</p>";
  ?>
```

Comment: Please create a new question instead of overwriting old ones. If an answer solves your question, you can mark it as accepted by pressing the green accept button on the left of the answer.

Comment: Also, the question MySQL vs Oracle in [this form](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4a575ad7-8305-4083-899d-9facf4072246/view-source) will be closed as a non-constructive question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of echoing the rows , save them to a variable. Then echo the calcuated value before eching the variable you saved. Observe:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close();



$output += "
<table border='1'>
      <tr>
      <th>Session ID</th>
      <th>TeacherUsername</th>
      <th>Teacher Name</th>
      <th>Module Number</th>
      <th>Module Name</th>
      <th>Course ID</th>
      <th>Course Name</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Student Username</th>
      <th>Student Name</th>
      <th>Mark</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      </tr>
";
       $total = 0;
        $count = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $count++;
          $total += $row['Mark'];
          $output += "
      <tr>
      <td>{$row['SessionId']}</td>
      <td>{$row['TeacherUsername']}</td>
      <td>{$row['TeacherForename']} {$row['TeacherSurname']}</td>
      <td>{$row['ModuleId']}</td>
      <td>{$row['ModuleName']}</td>
      <td>{$row['CourseId']}</td>
      <td>{$row['CourseName']}</td>
      <td>{$row['Year']}</td>
      <td>{$row['StudentUsername']}</td>
      <td>{$row['StudentForename']} {$row['StudentSurname']}</td>
      <td>{$row['Mark']}</td>
      <td>{$row['Grade']}</td>
      </tr>";
        }


          $output += "        </table>";

    $average = (int)($total/$count);
    echo "<p>Average Mark: $average</p>";
echo $output;
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a div above the table that is empty, and then use javascript to populate it

```
$("#div-you-created").html(<?php echo "Average Mark: $average"; ?>);
```

Comment: I get this error on the line you gave me: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in /web/stud/u0867587/Mobile_app/exam_grade_report.php on line 135.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to accomplish the task with PHP:

1. Store the fetched rows in an array and calculate the sum with PHP. Show the sum and then loop again through the saved rows
2. Run a SQL query fetching the total marks (or even sum). If your query is a simple `SELECT * FROM grades`, you can use `SELECT SUM(Mark) FROM grades` to get the sum of marks.

Comment: Can you implement the first way on my sample code, I'm new to php so I don't know this is done.

Answer (score 0):

instead of echoing the table, store the table in a string, then echo the average, then echo the string.